# Linux Lazarus: Wrong FileSize Reported by TFileStream

Tags: linux, file, filestream, filesize, lazarus

I am trying to read my file through Filestream to send it over the network and I have noticed something odd. I am not sure why.
My actual filesize is 44.7KB, but when filestream reads the same file it tells me that the filesize is 45228 Bytes or 45.2 KB. Why is that? Is there is a way to fix that?

```
fs:TFileStream;

fs := TFileStream.Create('myfile.dat', fmOpenRead or fmshareDenyWrite);

showmessage(inttostr(fs.Size));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that whatever you are using to report the file size is measuring the size using [kibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) (1024 bytes) rather than [kilobytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte) (1000 bytes).

Divide 45228 by 1024 to get 44.2KiB. This still doesn't match exactly but I would not be surprised if there was a transcription error in your question. There is at least one, where you wrote `FileSize` rather than `Size` (now corrected by a question edit) so my guess is that some of the other specific details are incorrect.

Other than that I think it very likely that the problem is in your other method of obtaining the file size. `TFileStream.Size` can be trusted to give an accurate value. If that doesn't tally with some other measure then that other measure is probably wrong.

On Linux you can use the `stat` command to get a definitive report of the file size. I would expect that to yield the same value as `TFileStream.Size`.

Comment: They both mean the same thing. I just typed it in that way. `FileSize=File Size`. I do read the file with Buffer size of 1024. If I change the size of my buffer, will it work correctly.

Comment: Er, I mean in the code. `fs.FileSize` does not compile, at least the way I read the FPC documentation. `TFileStream` has no property of that name.

Comment: It is still reporting the wrong file size even with `fs.size`.

Comment: I doubt it. I bet that the file size is 45228 bytes, and whatever other means you have for obtaining the size is wrong. Where did you pluck this 44.7KB figure from?

Comment: After carefully checking, I found out that the program I use "dolphin" which is like a windows explorer says that the file in question is 44.7KiB not KB. That is something new for me. On windows, I never came across anything like this before.

Comment: There will be a simple mistake somewhere. Use `stat` to confirm.

Comment: Yep, `stat` command returned 45228 bytes for the file. That matches with `TFileSteam.Size`